# Objective-C accessor template

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, model, macros, grand-central-dispatch

I've been working on a rewrite of my model layer to use across several existing apps.  The existing codebase is dated and I'd like to generalize my approach to lend to easier extension in the future and get the benefits of more recent language / technology additions (ARC for one).

My goal is a portable, SQL-backed "framework" consisting of a simple database layer (built on top of FMDatabase) and robust model object class which together encapsulate most of the complexity.  Model objects subclass from the main superclass and abide by a contract to implement (and override) methods that provide necessary property and schema details to facilitate SQL actions.

I've used this approach with much success in PHP but have run into issues with Objective-C.

Yes, CoreData provides these things but is not an option for a number of reasons.  I've also seen solutions that solve the problem at runtime but I'm not sure that would work with ARC, and would prefer to generate the accessors prior to compilation.

I started with the debate of maintaining a lock based pattern for multi-threaded access vs a GCD based approach [(question raised here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857581/multi-threaded-objective-c-accessors-gcd-vs-locks/15858078) and have ended up with the following pattern:

```
- (NSDate *)creationDate {
    __block NSDate *aDate;
    dispatch_sync(accessorQueue, ^{
        aDate = creationDate;
    });
    return aDate;
}

- (void)setCreationDate:(NSDate *)aDate {
    if (![aDate isKindOfClass: [NSDate class]]) {
        NSLog(@"setCreationDate: called with non-date object);
        return;
    }

    dispatch_barrier_async(accessorQueue, ^{
        if ((!creationDate && aDate) || ![aDate isEqualToDate: creationDate]) {
            [self willChangeValueForKey: @"creationDate"];

            [changes setObject: aDate ? aDate : [NSNull null]
                        forKey: @"creationDate"];

            creationDate = aDate;

            [self didChangeValueForKey: @"creationDate"];
        }
    });
}
```

I like it but I want to be able to generate for a list of properties to simplify the model object code.  My first step would be to create macro expansion to build the accessors/mutators.  Here I've already run into less-than-perfect options though.

1) Iterating on lists in macros is an ugly process.  Boost.preprocessor may be an option but considering (2 & 3) it kind of scares me.

2) Macros need to be passed in all possible versions of the tokens used (ie. I'd have to pass in creationDate and CreationDate just to satisfy generating the getter and setter for the example above.)  Not a show-stopper but not ideal either.

3) A different macro expansion is needed for object and primitive types which makes iterating  over a list of properties (1) even more difficult.  I could pass in the expansion macro for each property in the list but this "time saver" is now looking like quite the opposite – a long list of tuples is not much more readable than a list of individual calls to macros.

I'm hoping I've overlooked something that makes this possible or perhaps someone has already built a drop in solution that I haven't found.  Maybe a preprocessing script to generate categories containing the accessors...?  I haven't looked into that option yet but would be ok with it, especially if it extended to other languages for cross-platform targeting.

Advice appreciated.

Comment: I'd like to know your "number of reasons" for not using core data? Core data is brilliant, and you're not going to write a better version of it yourself.

Comment: 1) Your schema has to be reverse engineered making it very difficult to share cross-platform. For instance, I'm unaware of any standard layout techniques that would guarantee changes are limited in scope.  2) Issues exist using CoreData with iCloud (not that iCloud is a true solution for me) -- I need to provide a cross-platform syncing layer and prefer to be able to insert that where I think it makes the most sense.  3) I've been bitten hard by CoreData bugs in the past that were very time consuming to diagnose.  Those are the ones that are on the tip of my tongue.  #1 is a big one for me.

Comment: The cross-platform one is a pretty good reason, I suppose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a Python script that looks at the property declarations in my model object header files and writes out custom accessors in a new category for each class.  To facilitate this, I annotate my property declarations with a comment string of the form:

```
// SqlFieldName SqlFieldType
```

And I've defined several basic templates for object vs primitive accessors.

The results are very implementation specific but saves a lot of copy/paste/find/replace work for accessors which is usually a source of at least 1 bug due to oversight in renaming during find/replace.

Using a category to store the accessors leads to compilation warnings for overriding object methods in a category but you can silence those with -Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation.

My generated code is quite specific to my needs but if anyone is interested I'll post it.